# Avoiding select after flush when assigning to child relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy models:

```
class Parent(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id), nullable=False)

    parent = relationship(Parent, 
                          backref=backref('children',
                                          order_by=id,
                                          cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
```

And then I want to create a parent and some children, all in the same statement:

```
p = Parent()
DBSession.add(p)

# some unrelated code runs which triggers a flush

p.children = [Child(title=title) for title in titles]
```

That `p.children =` assignment statement triggers an unwanted `SELECT` statement, because SQLAlchemy has to clear out any pre-existing `Child` objects pointing to the `Parent`. I realize I can eliminate the `SELECT` statement with the `lazy='noload'` option on the backref, but I need this relationship to function normally (i.e. to fetch results from the DB) in other contexts.

Is there a way I can make a property that returns the value of a `noload` relationship, if it has been set, and otherwise uses a regular relationship to load the results from the DB? Or am I even thinking about this the right way?

Comment: Could you turn off auto-expire on your session?  Would that solve this?

Comment: Yes! Setting `DBSession.no_autoflush` eliminates the unwanted `SELECT` statement. I'll write it up.

Answer (score 2):

Sam in the comments pointed me to the right answer, `DBSession.no_autoflush`:

```
with DBSession.no_autoflush:
    p = Parent()
    DBSession.add(p)

    # some unrelated code runs which triggers a flush

    p.children = [Child(title=title) for title in titles]
```

This eliminates the unwanted `SELECT` statement when assigning to `p.children`.

Comment: Will this leave the old children intact in the DB, now that SQLA won't do the select, or is the clearing just postponed?

Comment: Because I just created the object, I know it doesn't have any children yet.

Comment: Right, missed that little tid bit of information in the post. Should read with thought.